# Cypher: Can we put if...else in where condition?

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am going to do a search. I have to put different condition for different person type. Could anybody tell me how to do this in Cypher? Cheers.

```
START ...
MATCH ...    
WHERE    
    if person.type! ='Teacher'
      ...//add condition
    else if person.type! ='Student'
      ...//add condition
    else if person.type!='Assistant'
      ...//add condition
    else 
      ...//add condition
Return ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to give you a complete answer without understanding what your `// add condition` should be doing.

However, I suspect that what you are looking for is `CASE`.

An example which may meet your requirements is something like this

```
MATCH (person:Person{name: "John"})
SET person.salary = 
CASE person.type
WHEN 'Teacher' THEN 50000
WHEN 'Assistant' THEN 40000
WHEN 'Student' THEN 0
ELSE NULL
END
RETURN person
```